# SWIFTUI - How to create an image linked to an URL?

Tags: url, hyperlink, swiftui

I would like to insert an URL to an image, I feel like it should be very simple but I couldn't make it work.

```
Button(action: {}) {
 Image("london").resizable().frame(width: 350.0, height: 233.0).buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            }
```

I want to go to "https://www.google.com" when the button is tapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open a url in a browser on the phone, you need to first construct the URL, then you have to check that the application can actually open it and only then you can ask the application to open the url for you.

```
 Button(action: {
     guard let google = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/"),
         UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(google) else {
         return
     }
     UIApplication.shared.open(google,
                               options: [:],
                               completionHandler: nil)
 }) {
    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 250.0,
               height: 233.0)
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
    }
```

Comment: I put the following code into the action of the button and it seems to be working, will I encounter problems with this?    UIApplication.shared.open (URL(string: "google.com" )!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

Comment: Potentially you might encounter problems. You should check whether url given can be opened (perhaps the user has no browser on their device, perhaps opening external websites is disabled with parental controls etc.). Also force unwrapping is never a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)` at action for the button.

Comment: I did "  UIApplication.shared.open (URL(string: "https://www.google.com" )!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil). and it worked.